# How to get more information about the Zookeeper status in Confluent

Tags: apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I am making Zookeeper cluster, and I separately start the Zookeeper in Confluent by using:

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
```

and I want to get the status of Zookeeper.

I search it online, and all of them is using:

```
./zkServer.sh status
```

But I can't find `zkServer.sh` in Confluent.

I know that I can use `./bin/confluent status` to get status. But I want more information about the Zookeeper like follow:

```
./zkServer.sh status
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/../conf/zoo.cfg 
Mode: follower
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Four Letter Words](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands) to get the same information or better instead.  The output from `stat`:

```
$ echo "stat" | nc <ZOOKEEPER-IP-ADDRESS> 2181
Zookeeper version: 3.4.10
Clients:
 /192.168.1.2:49618[1](queued=0,recved=1304,sent=1304)
 /192.168.1.3:53484[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/15
Received: 1330
Sent: 1329
Connections: 2
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x1000001ee
Mode: leader
Node count: 435
```

The output from `conf`:

```
$ echo "conf" | nc <ZOOKEEPER-IP-ADDRESS> 2181
clientPort=2181
dataDir=/var/zookeeper/data
dataLogDir=/var/log/zookeeper
tickTime=2000
maxClientCnxns=0
minSessionTimeout=4000
maxSessionTimeout=40000
serverId=3
initLimit=20
syncLimit=5
electionAlg=3
electionPort=3888
quorumPort=2888
peerType=0
```